# weighted average of rows dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to the the following more efficiently:

For data collected by "name", "date", "time", and an additional indicator variable "id", I would like to calculate the **daily weighted average** of the column "value", using the column "weights" as the weights in the average, by "id". An example of the original data is as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["A", "A", "A" ,"A", "A" ,"A", "B", "B", "B", "B"], "date":["06/24/2014","06/24/2014","06/24/2014","06/24/2014","06/25/2014","06/25/2014","06/25/2014","06/24/2014","06/24/2014","06/25/2014"], "time":['13:01:08', '13:46:53', '13:47:13', '13:49:11', '13:51:09', '14:35:03','15:35:00', '16:17:26', '16:17:26', '16:17:26'] , "id": ["B","B","S","S","S","B","S","B","S","S"], "value":[100.0, 98.0, 102.0, 80.0, 10.0, 200.0, 99.5, 10.0, 9.8, 10.0], "weights": [20835000.0, 3960000.0, 3960000.0, 3955000.0, 3960000.0, 5000000.0, 2000000.0, 6850.0, 162997.79999999999, 5000.0] })
```

After applying this function, the data should only have columns "name", "id", and "w_avg".

I have written the following function for this, using groupby:

```
df1 = df.groupby(['name','date','id'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: np.average(x['value'], weights=x['weights'])).unstack()
```

The output I get from this is the following:

```
id                        B          S
name date                             
A    06/24/2014   99.680581  91.006949
     06/25/2014  200.000000  10.000000
B    06/24/2014   10.000000   9.800000
     06/25/2014         NaN  99.276808
```

Now, for each "name" "date", I would like to  subtract the id's "B" from "S" to get a "diff" column.

To do this, I created a new data frame. To extract the indices I did:

```
name,date = zip(*list(df1.index.values))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name':name, 'date':date, 'B':list(df1['B']), 'S':list(df1['S'])})
df2['diff'] = df2['B'] - df2['S']
```

Can you suggest a way to do this is a more compact function? Also, I would like it to do it fast as I am processing several million rows. Is groupby the best way to do this?

Thank you,

Comment: What's wrong with `df1['diff'] = df1['B'] - df1['S']`?

Comment: Thank you EdChum. Yours is a good idea, however, I would like to have a "normal" data frame afterwards so that I can further operate on it.

Comment: why does this matter it will still work unless you have a specific requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and then substract:

```
df3 = df1.reset_index()

df3['diff'] = df3['B'] - df3['S']
print (df3)

id name        date           B          S        diff
0     A  06/24/2014   99.680581  91.006949    8.673632
1     A  06/25/2014  200.000000  10.000000  190.000000
2     B  06/24/2014   10.000000   9.800000    0.200000
3     B  06/25/2014         NaN  99.276808         NaN
```

EDIT:

It seems your solution is the fastest `len(df)=100k`:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [114]: %timeit (df.groupby(['name','date','id'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: np.average(x.value, weights=x.weights)))
10 loops, best of 3: 34.6 ms per loop

In [115]: %timeit ((df.value * df.weights).groupby([df.name,df.date,df.id]).sum() /  df.weights.groupby([df.name,df.date,df.id]).sum())
10 loops, best of 3: 38.4 ms per loop
```

But fastest solution is:

```
df['value'] = df.value * df.weights
g = df.groupby(['name','date','id']) 
print (g['value'].sum() / g['weights'].sum())

In [125]: %timeit (a(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 20 ms per loop
```

**Code for testing**:

```
def a(df):
    df['value'] = df.value * df.weights
    g = df.groupby(['name','date','id']) 
    return (g['value'].sum() / g['weights'].sum())

print (a(df))
```

EDIT1:

Comparing solution with original:

```
In [132]: %timeit (orig(df5))
10 loops, best of 3: 37.4 ms per loop

In [133]: %timeit (a(df))
10 loops, best of 3: 22.7 ms per loop
```

**Code for testing**:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)
df5 = df.copy()

def orig(df):

    df1 = df.groupby(['name','date','id'], as_index=False).apply(lambda x: np.average(x['value'], weights=x['weights'])).unstack()   
    name,date = zip(*list(df1.index.values))

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name':name, 'date':date, 'B':list(df1['B']), 'S':list(df1['S'])})
    df2['diff'] = df2['B'] - df2['S']
    df2 = df2[['name','date','B','S','diff']]
    return df2

def a(df):
    df['value'] = df.value * df.weights
    g = df.groupby(['name','date','id']) 
    df2 = (g['value'].sum() / g['weights'].sum()).unstack().reset_index()
    df2['diff'] = df2['B'] - df2['S']
    return df2    

print (orig(df5))    
print (a(df))
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael. Is groupby generally the fastest way to do this of this sort? As i mention in my post, I would like to do this for several million rows and can take about 10+ minutes.

Comment: Also, does reset_index convert a groupby object to a "normal" data frame?

Comment: Give me a sec, I try some tests.

Comment: reset index create new columns from multiindex and create `nice` index - "`range(len(df))`"

Comment: I tried your "fastest solution" for 14 million rows and it was indeed a lot faster than the one I proposed, thank you.